# Transferred production site to localhost now relative paths are messed up

Tags: cakephp, relative-path, directory-structure

I scp'd my entire production website locally so I could work on it with `git` and won't have to worry about editing a live website (it's not launched yet so I've only been doing it during development).

The thing is, my relative paths are messed up. I'm doing this on OS X within `~/bob_cobb/Sites` so previously I'd just include a file with

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen.css">`

and that would be relative to `/webroot/css`. Now, that same file is relative to

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/~bob_cobb/mywebsitefoldername/css/screen.css">`

How can I fix this? Do I need a symlink or something? I want to fix it so that when I push this to my repo on github it doesn't conflict when I pull on production.

This is a CakePHP site btw, so a typical directory structure looks like:

```
|-Sites
|--mywebsitefoldername
|---app
|----webroot
|-----css
|------screen.css
```

For my CSS and

```
|-Sites
|--mywebsitefoldername
|---app
|----View
|-----Layouts
|------default.ctp
```

for the index file that called all my scripts/css.

My local user settings in `/etc/apache2/users/bob_cobb.conf` are:

```
<Directory "/Users/bob_cobb/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

If it matters?

Comment: how do you include the CSS link ? Manually by writing the HTML code, or do you use the Cake HtmlHelper ?

Comment: @nIcO actually, I'm using the CakeHelper.. but if I include it with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/webroot/css/global.css">` it works... So I guess it's a problem with my cake path?

Comment: Try to update your Apache config with `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: @nIcO when I do that I get: `The requested URL /Users/bob_cobb/Sites/mywebsitename/app/webroot/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: you try to access `/Users/bob_cobb/Sites/mywebsitename/app/webroot/` as a URL ? The path should not contain `app/webroot`.

Comment: No, that's the message I get when I go to: `http://localhost/~bob_cobb/mywebsitename/` which is what I was doing before but with `AllowOverride None` and it worked. With `AllowOverride All` my htaccess files take over and I get that error on that URL.

Comment: Cake is supposed to work with its htaccess files. If it doesn't, you should first update your Apache config to correct this. Have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to copy .htaccess from the webroot in addition to everything else? scp ignores hidden files by default.

Comment: I downloaded them with the `-rp` flags so they are there.